# jquery expand / collapse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle

Im trying to make my jquery expand when clicked anywhere ( except the top left box ) and try to collapse when clicking only in the ( top left box )

http://jsfiddle.net/wzbAh/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="box">
    <div class="collapsed container" >
        <div class="nav" class="closed">0</div>
        box 1 - click me    
        <div class="expanded_content">
            extra content only for expanded state
        </div>
        <div class="collapsed_content">
            collapsed only content #1
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="collapsed container">

        <div class="nav" class="closed">0</div>
        box 2 - click me    
        <div class="expanded_content">
            extra content only for expanded state
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsed container">

        <div class="nav" class="closed">0</div>
        box 3 - click me    
        <div class="expanded_content">
            extra content only for expanded state
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#box").delegate(".container", "click", function(e) {
    $(this).addClass("expanded");
});

$("#box").delegate(".container.expanded .nav ", "click", function(e) {

    $(this).addClass("collapsed");
});
```

Seems to be almost there but not quite, what would be the right way to do it? Since toggle seems not the option here.

Comment: Are you using .delegate() because the elements aren't on the page initially? Also, .delegate() has been deprecated in favor of .on() since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: @j08691 - `delegate()` is not deprecated, `live` is.

Comment: @ShankarSangoli - Really? Try reading the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) first: "As of jQuery 1.7, .delegate() has been superseded by the .on() method."

Comment: @j08691 In the fiddle the OP is using jquery 1.5.2 which does not have `.on`

Comment: I can go to jquery 1.6 not 1.7

Comment: @j08691 - Check what did you commented **deprecated** which is not same as **superseded**. You can still use `delegate()`. So you read before commenting and advicing users.

Comment: @jk. - I was merely noting the change in .delegate() in the newer version of jQuery, not saying the OP had to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go mate...

```
$("#box").delegate(".container", "click", function(e) {
    if ($(e.target).hasClass("container")) {
        $(this).addClass("expanded");
    }
});

$("#box").delegate(".container.expanded .nav", "click", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("expanded");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

​

The class "collapsed" is never removed so to remove the expanded state you need to use `removeClass("expanded")`, so it goes back to its initial state.  Also, when the .nav element is clicked, the div you want to affect is the parent.

Finally, `e.stopPropagation()` stops the click firing both event handlers and removing the class and then adding it again.

Here's a working jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/wzbAh/11/

Comment: The upper left still expands the box: `Im trying to make my jquery expand when clicked anywhere ( except the top left box ) and try to collapse when clicking only in the ( top left box )`

Comment: Yes there are indeed multiple boxes on 1 page wich was also a problem for the expanding first.

Comment: I've added extra code now to check what the element that was clicked is, so it will only execute when it's the container.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#box").delegate(".container", "click", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is("div.nav")) {
       $(this).addClass("expanded");
    }
});

$("#box").delegate(".container .nav ", "click", function(e) {
    $(this).parent().removeClass("expanded").addClass("collapsed");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/wzbAh/9/